# Embedded Deployment service on EC2 instance not rendering

Tags: apex, aws, embedded-services

I created a screen flow and then an embedded service. I whitelisted the domain via CORS and CSP Trusted Sites.

Here is my URL to the ECP instance:
https://ec2-44-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

I added this Meta Tag to the header:

I also pasted the code snippet right before the closing body tag.

**What could be causing the Flow screen not to show?**

I noticed that the EC2 instance says "Not Secure." But other than that, I followed the SFDC instructions for embedded service deployments.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: Issue was that for some reason the entire Script was being commented out when I deployed it on the site.